# WP configuration page for theme in combination with ACF?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I'm making a WP Boiler plate theme for my future projects. I make heavy use of Advanced Custom Fields. I'm looking for a way to add a page to my theme with basic info for a project, like phone number, opening hours, email address, etc. I want it to be a specific page, accessible in the admin menu. With ACF I could then add the different input fields for different projects. What I've figured  out I could do it with a custom post type, but then you could add multiple posts with phone numbers etc, which would be confusing for clients. In an ideal world, it should be just one page (or php file?), automatically created by the theme, and then I could manually add fields to that page with ACF. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make a start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page and get a page added to your site. Then you can add in your ACF fields etc as needed to that page. Hope that helps - reply if you need more.